# not able to access $scope object outside a http response callback function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this controller for saving some details for an individual. I have a separate repository EntityRepository where a function to get the user gender from database is defined.

The function response is working correctly and when I am printing the gender on console inside the function response it works(console.log("inside : ", $scope.userGender);).

But outside the function the value is not undefined I am getting(console.log("outside : ", $scope.userGender);)

```
.controller('individualDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, EntityRepository) {
 $scope.userGender = "";
 $scope.entity = {
   name: "",
   gender: $scope.userGender,
   dob: "",
   pan: ""
 };
 EntityRepository.getUserGender()
 .then(function(response){
   $scope.userGender = response.data.gender;
   console.log("inside : ", $scope.userGender);
 })
 .catch(function(errorResponse) {
   $scope.error = errorResponse.data
 });
 console.log("outside : ", $scope.userGender);
});
```

I want to save the gender from the response in the $scope.entity.gender but I am not able to access the value of $scope.userGender outside the function scope.

Since $scope is defined in the scope of controller I think it should be able to access its values outside the function response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't access the value of `$scope.userGender` outside the AJAX success callback is simple: AJAX is asynchronous, meaning that a value to this variable will be assigned only after this AJAX call succeeds. You should adapt your code so that it doesn't depend on the value of `$scope.userGender` before this AJAX call has succeeded. If this value is data bound to some control in the markup, then this is not a problem, the value will appear with a little delay when the value is retrieved from the server.

Comment: What do you want to correct? There's nothing wrong with your code. That's how AJAX works. Use the `$scope.userGender` variable inside the AJAX success callback, not outside of it. Adapt your code so that it works using callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access the value outside due to **asynchronous** property of requests. What that simply means is that this statement: `console.log("outside : ", $scope.userGender);`, is getting executed before the `.then(function(){ ... })`.

Fixes:

1. Wrap your outside code inside of `$timeout`

`.controller('individualDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, EntityRepository, $timeout) {`

and

`$timeout(function() {console.log("outside : ", $scope.userGender)});`

2. Use `$scope.userGender`'s value only inside the `.then(function() { })`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
  $scope.GetUserGender = function(){
 EntityRepository.getUserGender().then(function(response){
    $scope.userGender = response.data.gender;
    console.log("inside : ", $scope.userGender);
  }).catch(function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.data
  });     
}
  $scope.GetUserGender();   //

 console.log("outside : ", $scope.userGender);
```

Hope this will work :)